# Why does importing usb.core work in the shell, but not in a new window?

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb

My problem is when I try to import `usb.core` or `usb` or just `usb.util` outside the shell window, in a new window. When I hit run, on the shell windows its says

`"ImportError: No module named core".`

But when I import `usb` on the shell window or in python command line it works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

Your PYTHONPATH is being set differently in the shell than in your target window.

Run this code to be sure:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Compare on both platforms.

Comment: This is what i get in the shell:
['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']

Comment: And this in a new window:
['C:/Users/Martinez/Desktop', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']

How do I change the path?

Comment: sys.path.append, or pass it as the PYTHONPATH variable. Python in Windows is never going to be fun.

Comment: I changed my path but its still not working, only with the shell windows! what else can i Do???